# JavaScript validates variable types different when they are undefined and null

Tags: javascript, function, statements

I saw this question in a test, where the variable myObj was not declared, and requsted to choose the correct answer based on the following if statements.

```
function myFunction() {
  if(typeof myObj !== "undefined" && myObj !== null) {
    a = 1
  }
}

result: "undefined"
```

Created the functions to run these statements and test output.

```
 function myFunction() {
   if(myObj !== null && typeof myObj !== "undefined") {
    a = 1
   }
 }

 result: Uncaught ReferenceError: myObj is not defined
```

my questions is if an variable is not defined, isn't that the same as "undefined", if I want to test for a "undefined" value, I can just use "null" to check if its undefined by (e.g myObj === null), so why is the fist function returns undefined and the second returns myObj is not defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on:

1. Value checks are different from type checks.

   If you try to read the value of an identifier that doesn't exist, you get an error. So `myObj === null` causes an error if `myObj` doesn't exist (the identifier has never been declared or otherwise created).

   But using `typeof` on an identifier that doesn't exist results in `"undefined"`, without an error. So `typeof myObj` is `"undefined"` when `myObj` doesn't exist. You can see this in [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-typeof-operator) where it does:

   > 2(a) If IsUnresolvableReference(val) is true, return "undefined".
2. The `&&` operator *short-circuits*.

   `&&` evaluates its first operand and, if that value is falsy,¹ takes the falsy value as its result, doing nothing with the second operand. If the first operand's value is truthy, though, `&&` evaluates the second operand and takes that value as its result.

Because of those two things, `if(typeof myObj !== "undefined" && myObj !== null) {` works without error because it does `typeof myObj !== "undefined"` first and, since that value is `false` when `myObj` doesn't exist, the result of the `&&` operation is `true` and the second operand is never evaluated. But `if(myObj !== null && typeof myObj !== "undefined") {` does `myObj !== null` first, trying to use the value of an identifier that doesn't exist, which causes the error.

> my questions is if an variable is not defined, isn't that the same as "undefined"

Not in the general case, no. `typeof` is special. Just about anything else you do with an identifier that doesn't exist will raise an error. (Okay, there's one other thing: in loose mode, if you assign to an identifier that doesn't exist, it creates a global. This is what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) and is one of the many reasons to use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), where it's the error it always should have been.)

---

¹ "truthy" and "falsy" are terms we use in JavaScript to refer to vlaues that coerce to `true` and values that coerce to `false` when used as conditions. There is a fixed set of falsy values: `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course, `false` (also `document.all` in browsers; weird but true). All other values are truthy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your understanding of && operator in JavaScript,

explaining with a example : expr1 && expr2

If expr1 can be converted to true, returns expr2; else, returns expr1.

In your first case :
typeof myObj !== "undefined" // this is false, because typeof myObj is undefined
so it returns undefined.

In your second case :
myObj !== "null" // this gives Uncaught ReferenceError: myobj is not defined, as this is
not true , the same error is returned